# Dynamically render template without reloading page

Tags: javascript, flask, handlebars.js

Just started making a Flask app to make a simple Wizard. For now I have just two "Steps", each with its own HTML templated file; Jinja is the templating language. The first pass at this makes it so that on "Next" and "Previous" it routes to a new page.

Simple enough but now I want to convert this into a one-page app. Using Handlebars it was as simple as having a main container div, then rendering separate templates when clicking next/previous buttons.

Is there a way to do this in Flask? A way to use JS or Flask to render or load a template HTML file to a div container?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use AJAX to load content from the server without reloading the whole page.

As an example:

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  $(document).ready( function() {
        $('#next').click(function() {
           $.ajax("{{ url_for('myroute') }}").done(function (reply) {
              $('#container').html(reply);
           });
        });
  });
</script>

<input type="button" id="next" value="Next" />
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Beautiful. Got it up and running. Exactly the answer I was looking for.

Comment: One problem with this: if my new url has Jinja templating (python) it gives a 500 error because it can't load it. Is there a workaround?